# Get the eigenvalues when you know the explained variances of a PCA plot

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, unsupervised-learning, eigenvalues

I'm performing a PCA using the `sklearn.decomposition.pca` function.

It appears to work as it should. Acording to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909945/obtain-eigen-values-and-vectors-from-sklearn-pca), I can get the eigenvalues like this:.

> The eigenvalues represent the variance in the direction of the eigenvector. So you can get them through the pca.explained_variance_ attribute:
>
> `eigenvalues = pca.explained_variance_`

If this is correct, the eigenvalues for my first few components seem to be way to high.

```
eigenvalues = pca.explained_variance_
eigenvalues # returns  [1188.482427    760.26572144  581.29434167  325.56710676  267.10095401
  219.49301802  155.1603308   107.8855256    76.17770897   64.09568959]
```

For every scree-plot I've seen and for example, when you google screeplot on google, the eigenvalues are usually much, much lower. Can eigenvalues be this high?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sklearn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) doesn't scale your data:

> The input data is centered but not scaled for each feature before
>   applying the SVD.

Your variances are high because your feature variances are high. In general, standardization is recommended because otherwise some of your features with low values won't be represented well.